# Event in a child iframe to a handler in the parent window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

My scenario is to open a modal that contains iframe ,inside the iframe having button while onclick   button i need to close the modal and refresh the parent window
**So far i tried**
**Parent page :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    // $('iframe').content ().find('#close').click(function(){
    //   alert('entred');

    // });
    $('#myModal').contents().find('#close').click(function() {
      alert('click');
    });
  });
</script>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Modal Example</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <iframe src="modal.html"></iframe>
  </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**Child Page**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <p>Hello Session has expeired</p>
        <button id="close" type="button">OK</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Parent Page, update the below script which will create a global function called `closeModal` which will 1) Close the modal dialog and 2) Reloads the current page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.closeModal = function () {
        $('#myModal').modal('hide');
        window.location.reload();
    };
</script>
```

In Child Page, on `Close` button click, simply call the `closeModal` method of the parent.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#close').click(function () {
            window.parent.closeModal();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Its works thank you ,can u please explain me how its works

Comment: In parent page, I create global method which has direct access to `#myModal` div. Then in child page, I call the global method which is registered in parent window.

Comment: Thank You So Much @PhaniKumarM

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to give your iFrame an ID, and then attach a handler to either it, or an element within:

```
document.getElementById("yourIFrameId").contentDocument.addEventListener(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should to do what you need:

ParentPage.html:

```
<iframe src="iframe.html"></iframe>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
    $(document).on('eventhandler', function() {               
      $('#myModal').modal('hide');
    });
}); 
</script>
```

ChildPage.html:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
 $('#close').click(function () {
    parent.$(parent.document).trigger('eventhandler');  
});
</script>
```